# Docx paragraph unicode

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

I'm using python 2.7.11
docx 0.8.6

I want to get text from doc.paragraphs
When my paragraph has polish signs such as łąćśńźż etc. i got error (if paragraph has no such signs, it works well:

in change_doc_paragraph
    print paragraph.text
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'

How to solve that problem?

@scanny Here you have code:

```
doc = docx.Document(<pathToDoc>)
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    print paragraph.text
```

And your doc should have some of those signs łŁĄąĘęŚśĆćŻżŹźŃńÓó

Comment: You'll need to post the minimum code that reproduces the error. Also you should format it as code by indenting by four spaces. The line you posted is not working code.

Comment: I have edited the main post

Comment: I don't see how that code could give rise to that error. If you: `print type(paragraph)` instead of `print paragraph.text`, what do you get? You would be expecting a docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph object, not a 'unicode' object. Can you try again and post exact code and exact stack trace? I think you must have missed something.

Comment: This is exact code. paragraph.text returns me text of paragraph (so, as expected), but if you have mentioned signs in it, this exception is raised, as mystically paragraph type was changed to Unicode type.

Comment: I need the full stack trace, not just the exception raised.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare coding first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and then type:

```
u'łŁĄąĘęŚśĆćŻżŹźŃńÓó'
```